# sed or tr one-liner to delete all numeric digits

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

So, I have this textfile, and it consists of mostly alphanumeric characters. It's a standard document. But since I copied it and pasted it from a PDF, there are page numbers in there. I don't much care for the occasional number that's not a page, so I figure I'll wipe them all out with `sed` or `tr`. Just marginally faster than find and replacing first zero, then one, then two, etc. in the GUI, after all.

So how do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove all digits, here are a few possibilities:

```
tr -d 0-9 <old.txt >new.txt
tr -d '[:digit:]' <old.txt >new.txt
sed -e 's/[0-9]//g' <old.txt >new.txt
```

If you just want to get rid of the page numbers, there's probably a better regexp you can use, to recognize just those digits that are page numbers. For example, if the page numbers are always alone on a line except for whitespace, the following command will delete just the lines containing nothing but a number surrounded by whitespace:

```
sed -e '/^ *[0-9]\+ *$/d' <old.txt >new.txt
```

(`\+` is a GNU extension; with some `sed` implementations, you may need the longer standard alternative: `\{1,\}` or use `[0-9][0-9]*`).

You don't need to use the command line for this, though. Any halfway decent editor has regexp search and replacement capabilities.

Comment: What about `sed -ibak -e 's/[0-9]//g' file.txt`?

Comment: gotta love that tr syntax. whoever wrote that program was a kindred spirit, i imagine, because i personally have always found sed and grep eyesores. i know i don't *have* to use the command line. these days i automatically revert to CL after a certain number of clicks (maybe 3) is required for something because i know later on it will be useful to me to know how to do so... but thanks for the sed command you give at the end because honestly i would love to have mastered regex and it would serve me greatly and of all the commands above it's actually the one that i will end up using.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
tr -d 0-9
```

Comment: `tr -d '[0-9]'` would remove brackets as well. `tr -d [0-9]` usually removes brackets and digits, but may do something else if there is a file whose name is a single digit in the current directory.